# Regexp in Apache 2.4 when used in HTTP_USER_AGENT var

Tags: apache-2.4, regex, regular-expressions

I need to work with some user-agents in Apache 2.4. I googled a lot for examples, tried a million regex options, and it still doesn't work:

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == '/^.*(Google|bing|Windows|Gecko).*$/'">
Require all granted
</If>
```

Meanwhile, RegExp as such works fine (see https://regexr.com/7lar4 ). And it clearly points to my wrong homebrew Apache syntax.

This is what I already tried as well:

```
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == '^.*(Google|bing|Windows|Gecko).*$'">
Require all granted
</If>

<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} == '~/^.*(Google|bing|Windows|Gecko).*$/'">
Require all granted
</If>
```

And so on. Nothing worked.

Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

After wasting another hour, I can say that the correct syntax is:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.(?=(doc|docx|pdf|ppt|rtf|xls|xlsx)$)[^\.]+?$">
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /^.*(Googlebot|Google-InspectionTool|GoogleOther|GoogleOther|bingbot|YandexBot|YandexImages|YandexMetrika|YandexWebmaster|Baiduspider).*$/">
Require all granted
</If>
</FilesMatch>
```

This config part will allow major bots to crawl office files.

Apache 2.4 of abore is required.